# Add conditionalPanel to multiple navbarMenus in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a shiny application with multiple `navbarMenus` and `tabPanel`s. Each `navBarMenu` has separate `conditionalPanel`s. When I add a second `navBarMenu` in the code snippet below, the `conditionalPanel` doesn't seem to work for the `tabPanel`s as all input appear on all `tabPanel`s. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
  ui <- shinyUI(tagList(
  shinythemes::themeSelector(),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    .shiny-output-error-validation {
                    color: green;
                    }
                    "))
    ),
  navbarPage(title = "Test App",
             navbarMenu("nav bar 1", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                        "menu 1",
                        "--------",
                        tabPanel("Tab1", 
                                 tabPanel("panel 1", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                                          pageWithSidebar(
                                            headerPanel(""),
                                            sidebarPanel(tags$head(
                                              tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                              tags$style(type="text/css", ".span4 { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                              tags$style(type="text/css", ".well { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                              tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:200px; float:left;}')
                                            ),
                                            conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==1",
                                                             dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Select Date Range:", start = "2017-01-01", end = Sys.Date(), width = "100%")
                                            ),
                                            conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==2",
                                                               dateRangeInput("daterange2", "Select Date Range:", start = "2017-01-01", end = Sys.Date(), width = "100%"),
                                                               selectInput("inputw1", "Select cols:", choices = c("col1","col2","col3"), selected = "col1", multiple = FALSE, width = "100%")
                                            ),
                                            conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==3"
                                            )
                                            ),
                                            mainPanel(
                                              tabsetPanel(id = "conditionedPanels",
                                                          tabPanel("tab 1", value = 1, icon = icon("table"), 
                                                                   br(),
                                                                   h3("Data Table")
                                                          ),
                                                          tabPanel("tab 2", value=2, icon = icon("line-chart"),
                                                                   column(width = 5, leafletOutput("map1")
                                                                   )
                                                          ),
                                                          tabPanel("tab 3", value=3 , icon = icon("table"),
                                                                   tinyMCE('editor1', 'Click to edit text')
                                                          )
                                              )
                                            )
                                          )
                                 )
                        )

             ),

             navbarMenu("nav bar 2", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                        "menu 1",
                        "--------",
                        tabPanel("Tab1", 
                                 tabPanel("panel 2", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                                          pageWithSidebar(
                                            headerPanel(""),
                                            sidebarPanel(tags$head(
                                              tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                              tags$style(type="text/css", ".span4 { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                              tags$style(type="text/css", ".well { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                              tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:200px; float:left;}')
                                            ),
                                            conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==4",
                                                             dateRangeInput("daterange3", "Select Date Range:", start = "2014-01-01", end = Sys.Date(), width = "100%")
                                            ),
                                            conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==5",
                                                             dateRangeInput("daterange4", "Select Date Range:", start = "2014-01-01", end = Sys.Date(), width = "100%"),
                                                             selectInput("inputw2", "Select cols:", choices = c("col4","col5","col6"), selected = "col1", multiple = FALSE, width = "100%")
                                            ),
                                            conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==6"
                                            )
                                            ),
                                            mainPanel(
                                              tabsetPanel(id = "conditionedPanels",
                                                          tabPanel("tab 1", value = 4, icon = icon("table"), 
                                                                   br(),
                                                                   h3("Data Table")
                                                          ),
                                                          tabPanel("tab 2", value=5, icon = icon("line-chart"),
                                                                   column(width = 5, leafletOutput("map1")
                                                                   )
                                                          ),
                                                          tabPanel("tab 3", value=6 , icon = icon("table"),
                                                                   tinyMCE('editor2', 'Click to edit text')
                                                          )
                                              )
                                            )
                                          )
                                 )
                        )

             )



  )

    )
)

  server <- function(input, output, session){
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I appreciate any help I can get with fixing my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is not because of second `navBarMenu` it is because the you have two output element with the same name in the two tabs i.e. `leafletOutput("map1")`. **You are not allowed to give the two output elements the same name.**

So changing `leafletOutput("map1")` to `leafletOutput("map2")` for second `tabsetPanel` fixes the issue you reported.

The second problem that you will encounter after fixing this issue is that both your `tabsetPanel` have the same id i.e. `conditionedPanels` which will cause only your first `tabsetPanel` to make your `conditionalPanel` work properly. To fix this issue you have to change the id of your one `tabsetPanel`.

I have changed the value of your `leafletOutput` and `tabsetPanel` id in your code to get the desired output.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinyMCE)

   ui <- shinyUI(tagList(
     shinythemes::themeSelector(),
     tags$head(
       tags$style(HTML("
                       .shiny-output-error-validation {
                       color: green;
                       }
                       "))
     ),
     navbarPage(title = "Test App",
                navbarMenu("nav bar 1", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                           "menu 1",
                           "--------",
                           tabPanel("Tab1", 
                                    tabPanel("panel 1", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                                             pageWithSidebar(
                                               headerPanel(""),
                                               sidebarPanel(tags$head(
                                                 tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                                 tags$style(type="text/css", ".span4 { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                                 tags$style(type="text/css", ".well { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                                 tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:200px; float:left;}')
                                               ),
                                               conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==1",
                                                                dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Select Date Range:", start = "2017-01-01", end = Sys.Date(), width = "100%")
                                               ),
                                               conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==2",
                                                                dateRangeInput("daterange2", "Select Date Range:", start = "2017-01-01", end = Sys.Date(), width = "100%"),
                                                                selectInput("inputw1", "Select cols:", choices = c("col1","col2","col3"), selected = "col1", multiple = FALSE, width = "100%")
                                               ),
                                               conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==3"
                                               )
                                               ),
                                               mainPanel(
                                                 tabsetPanel(id = "conditionedPanels",
                                                             tabPanel("tab 1", value = 1, icon = icon("table"), 
                                                                      br(),
                                                                      h3("Data Table")
                                                             ),
                                                             tabPanel("tab 2", value=2, icon = icon("line-chart"),
                                                                      column(width = 5, leafletOutput("map1")
                                                                      )
                                                             ),
                                                             tabPanel("tab 3", value=3 , icon = icon("table"),
                                                                      tinyMCE('editor1', 'Click to edit text')
                                                             )
                                                 )
                                               )
                                             )
                                    )
                           )

                ),

                navbarMenu("nav bar 2", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                           "menu 1",
                           "--------",
                           tabPanel("Tab1", 
                                    tabPanel("panel 2", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                                             pageWithSidebar(
                                               headerPanel(""),
                                               sidebarPanel(tags$head(
                                                 tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                                 tags$style(type="text/css", ".span4 { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                                 tags$style(type="text/css", ".well { max-width: 400px; }"),
                                                 tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:200px; float:left;}')
                                               ),
                                               conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels1==4",
                                                                dateRangeInput("daterange3", "Select Date Range:", start = "2014-01-01", end = Sys.Date(), width = "100%")
                                               ),
                                               conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels1==5",
                                                                dateRangeInput("daterange4", "Select Date Range:", start = "2014-01-01", end = Sys.Date(), width = "100%"),
                                                                selectInput("inputw2", "Select cols:", choices = c("col4","col5","col6"), selected = "col1", multiple = FALSE, width = "100%")
                                               ),
                                               conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels1==6"
                                               )
                                               ),
                                               mainPanel(
                                                 tabsetPanel(id = "conditionedPanels1",
                                                             tabPanel("tab 1", value = 4, icon = icon("table"), 
                                                                      br(),
                                                                      h3("Data Table")
                                                             ),
                                                             tabPanel("tab 2", value=5, icon = icon("line-chart"),
                                                                      column(width = 5, leafletOutput("map2")
                                                                      )
                                                             ),
                                                             tabPanel("tab 3", value=6 , icon = icon("table"),
                                                                      tinyMCE('editor2', 'Click to edit text')
                                                             )
                                                 )
                                               )
                                             )
                                    )
                           )

                )



     )

   )
   )

   server <- function(input, output, session){   }

   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @SBista! This solved the issue. I need to thoroughly review my codes next time. I'll accept your answer

Comment: I noticed the white space between the sidebar panel and the main panel. Do you know how to get rid of it? I've tried without luck. Thanks again for your help with the previous solution.